# ¿Debo hacer un pull antes de un push, si sé que alguien estuvo modificando el código mientras yo también lo hacía?

Tags: git

Tengo una duda, a continuación el proceso:

1- Dos personas comienzan a trabajar al mismo tiempo sobre un proyecto. Antes de empezar hacen un pull para asegurarse de que tienen su repositorio local actualizado.

2- Uno de ellos realiza un cambio, lo envía al repositorio local mediante un nuevo commit y, posteriormente, lo envía al repositorio remoto.

3- Luego de esto, el otro usuario, quien también ha realizado un cambio, envía el mismo a su repositorio local mediante un nuevo commit y, al momento de enviar el cambio al repositorio remoto le surge la siguiente duda:

**¿Debo primero ejecutar un pull para descargar las modificaciones realizadas por mi compañero, antes de enviar mi modificaciones, o puedo enviar mis modificaciones y luego hacer un pull para actualizar mi repositorio local con las modificaciones realizadas por mi compañero?**

Comment: Yo no lo consideraría duplicado, en la otra pregunta se esta tratando de resolver una falla, en esta pregunta se quiere saber si se debe hacer pull antes o después.

Comment: Git no te va a dejar hacer **push** si hay nuevos commits en el repositorio remoto, así que te toca hacer **pull** por obligación

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo ideal es siempre hacer un `pull` para que tu repositorio local este siempre actualizado, generalmente los pasos que ocupo yo antes de hacer un commit es :

```
git pull origin...
//Verifico que este actualizado, si no obviamente se bajan los cambios
git commit -a -m "...."
git push origin ....
```

En el caso que tu o tu compañero hayan modificado el mismo código, se generará un conflicto que tendrás que resolver.

Comment: Recordá que los dos usuarios comienzan a realizar modificaciones en el proyecto al mismo tiempo, con la diferencia de que uno envía sus modificaciones primero que el otro. No sé si eso influye en tu respuesta o no.

Comment: Lo que puede influir es que tocaron el mismo codigo y eso generara un conflicto que el usuario tiene que resolver

Comment: Bien, ahora entiendo. Si no tocaron la misma parte del código, con un pull seguido de un push se resuelve la situación. Gracias.